# High side IGBT for negative voltages

Tags: gate-driving, igbt

I am trying to figure design a circuit using IGBT whose collector is connected to 0V (machine ground) and emitter is connected to -800VDC (negative). I am using IRS2113 high side low side driver. How should I connect the common pin of IRS2113 whether 0V or -800VDC.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking basic questions about dangerous voltages really needs a tag of its own.

Comment: @BrianDrummond:  Idunno.  The question itself is valid (how to drive an IGBT for negative voltages?)  In combination with the rest of the info, it just means that the answer becomes "if you have to ask how to do it, then you shouldn't be doing it."  The combination (basic question and high voltage) scares the willies out of me, too.  I think asking and being told "you don't know enough to do this" is valuable information for some people - and may let a budding engineer live long enough to become an engineer some day.

Comment: @JRE: What is worse though is if the question is kept and answered and the OP blows itself up because the answer can not possibly contains everything he needs to know not to do. Plus more people coming here, reading it, and blowing themselves up. OTOH, maybe thats just what the darwin award is for...

Comment: Oh and btw. the datasheet of the 2113 I have available does by no means go to 800V

Comment: @JRE Agreed that using an IGBT in an unusual configuration is a valid topic, and could give rise to a good question. But I'm still not convinced this is it. The very wording of the question suggests a dead short across an 800V supply though the schematic, fortunately, says otherwise.

Comment: @BrianDrummond:  I've added my vote to close to yours.

Answer (score 4):

Before the masses close this question, I think it deserves an answer.

If you refer to the datasheet, you will see it clearly states the operating limits of the IRS2113. Second line on page 1:

[image: datasheet page 1]

"Fully operational to \$+600\mathrm{V}\$". So basically if you try and use it in a circuit to drive an IGBT with a high side voltage of \$+800\mathrm{V}\$, you will blow it up. So if you were using a +ve voltage rather than a negative one things would be very bad.

So now the question is, what if you go negative as in your schematic. Well, you want to connected to a high side of \$+0\mathrm{V}\$, which for the bootstrap pin is fine. You are also trying to connect the low size to \$-800\mathrm{V}\$.

Lets refer to the datasheet once more:

[image: datasheet screenshot]

Ok, so the first problem, "High Side Output Voltage". This is allowed to be between \$V_s-0.3\mathrm{V}\$ and \$V_b+0.3\mathrm{V}\$. Now you have \$V_s=V_b=0\mathrm{V}\$, which means \$V_{ho}=0-20=-20\mathrm{V}\$. Now clearly that is out of spec for the device. You would fry the high side driver.

Second, and rather critical problem: "Low Side Output Voltage". According to the datasheet, this is allowed to be between \$-0.3\mathrm{V}\$ and \$V_{cc}+0.3\mathrm{V}\$. So what do you think would happen if you try to connect it to an IGBT whose emitter is at \$-800\mathrm{V}\$? Well, the gate voltage will be switched between \$-800\mathrm{V}\$ and \$V_{cc}-800\mathrm{V}\$. Now unless I am mistaken, both of those numbers are far far far beyond the rating of the driver. So that would very quickly go bang.

Now I don't know what IGBT you are using, but aside from my doubts that one would withstand that kind of voltage at its gate (it won't, trust me), you will be switching the low side between On and On. So what would happen if you turned on the high side as well?

Think connecting \$0\mathrm{V}\$ directly to \$-800\mathrm{V}\$...

---

So in summary, you have devised a circuit which **will** destroy itself in a rapid and energetic fashion. This will lead quickly to either **death** by electrocution, or in the ensuing fire.

## DO NOT EVER WIRE UP THAT CIRCUIT!